# HTML validation message in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have validation on my form.

For example:

```
if(!this.$siteName.get(0).checkValidity()){
 //
}

if(!this.$title.get(0).checkValidity()){
 /
}
```

So, i have problem in firefox in this case:
I check the element, then the form contains it, can hide. In chrome, if the element hides, the error message will hide too. But in firefox, i guess, they do not check the visibility of the element - doesn't.

Here is screens from Chrome (just for example) and Firefox (after menu is hide):

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Is there some workarounds to hide the message by js?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You can customize these messages, check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Comment: For what my code)? Problem in error message) Menu slides up, and message in firefox still visible :)) Can i close it by js? Or there is some hack to do it

Comment: This is standart message implemented by the browsers